# Keystroke Dynamics on jQuery

Tags: jquery, security, authentication

I'd like to add to a quite sensitive login area some security. I've read about Keystroke Dynamics and I find it very interesting: if the typing pattern isn't recognized I can ask more info. Are there any jQuery implementations? Could you give me other hints about behavioral two-factor auth?

Answer (score 3):

There is no universal, freely given, solution how to use Keystroke Dynamic in any project (as I know). But, you can use basic jQuery function to calculate dynamics between letters, then send it with your login and password to server and server can evaluate differences in dynamics given now and stored when you register new user (you need own algorithm).
I create for you a short example.

[**Online demo** for save Keystroke dynamics with javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/qLap9/)

```
var tmr = []; // array to save keyup times
$('#pwd').keyup(function(evt) {
    tmr.push({"tmr":evt.timeStamp,
              "cod":evt.which});
    console.log("Key code: "+evt.which+" On time: "+evt.timeStamp);
});
```

Then, you can send result with password and login like any other input from html form.
You calculate times for dynamics like this:

```
    var ret = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < tmr.length - 1; ++i) {
        ret += ((i>0)?";":"") + (tmr[i+1].tmr - tmr[i].tmr);
    }
```

Then, you own must create script for evalueate actual dynamics with dynamics stored for user. Perhaps I assist you a little. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is more complex and it's not something you can do with just JavaScript. Authentication itself is done by using complex machine learning algorithms over an API. JavaScript is used only for recording typing patterns.

At [TypingDNA](http://typingdna.com/) I've written [a JavaScript implementation](http://typingdna.com/scripts/typingdna.js) that comes with Apache license (you can use freely to record typing patterns in web pages), however if you want to actually perform authentication, you'll have to use the API.

If you have specific questions let me know.